# How can i create an array that contains another array?

Tags: android, arrays, list

I need to save some values that i get it from a listview, my question is how can i do this implementation to save my values?
I need to do this.

```
[
    {
        "id_question": "my value here",
        "answers": [
            {
                "my_answer":"value for this answer",
                "id_answer":"my value here"
            },
            {
                "my_answer":"value for this answer",
                "id_answer":"my value here"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Recently i use

```
List<Map<String, String>[]> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>[]>();
```

Comment: You can save in Shared Preference.

Comment: Sorry recently i edited my question , i dont want to save i want to create that structure in android.

Comment: Why would you use that? That's a List containing an array of Maps. You're probably looking for `List<Map<String, Object>>` with casting to `List<Map<String, String>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer.java*

```
public class Answer {
     private String myAnswer;
     private String idAnswer;
     //constructor, setters and getters
}
```

*Question.java*

```
public class Question {
     private String question;
     private List<Answer> answerList;
     //constructor, setters and getters
}
```

In your current class

```
private List<Question> questionList;
```

If what I understand by the term “saving” in your question as saving to local db, then these classes can directly be converted to Realm Classes.

P.S. Simple way to get to this data structure is to stick to basics. That is objects are representation of real time entity.

Comment: Hi Mohammed thanks , I understand that example, but i want to send a similar structure like in my example because i need to send it to php , in php i need to receive an structure like that, i updated my question because i dont want to save it, i want to created it a similar structure, sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: @Hugo Ramos you can use GSON as mentioned by Amit to convert above data structure to json directly. or you can create json objects directly using combination of JsonObject and Jsonarray